# HashMap with FXML JavaFX won't find my key

Tags: java, javafx, hashmap, fxml

why can my Circle not be found or why is value null? I cannot find a solution to fix my HashMap or how to access the Circle in question.

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class Connect4 {

    @FXML
    private Circle A1;
    Map<String, Circle> circles = new HashMap<>() {{
        put("A1", A1);
    }};


    public void clickOnRectangleA(MouseEvent e) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(circles.containsValue(A1));
        circles.get("A1").setFill(SomeColor);
    }
}
```

My Console:

```
false
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1862)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1729)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3563)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3865)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1851)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2584)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:299)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:447)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:412)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:446)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1857)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.shape.Circle.setFill(javafx.scene.paint.Paint)" because the return value of "java.util.Map.get(Object)" is null
    at de.medieninformatik.prog2.Connect4.clickOnRectangleA(Connect4.java:190)
    ... 40 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `FXXMLLoader` loads the FXML file, it

1. Creates an instance of the controller class
2. Injects any fields annotated `@FXML` with elements with matching `fx:id`s
3. Calls the `initialize()` method, if there is one

In your code, you call `put("A1", A1)` in the (anonymous) constructor of a `HashMap` subclass which is initialized inline. So this code is executed when the controller class is instantiated (step 1 above). This happens *before* `A1` is injected, so at that time it is null. I.e. you are calling `put("A1", null)`, which of course does not associate any value in the map with the key `"A1"`.

Instead, put the value in the map in the `initialize()` method:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class Connect4 {

    @FXML
    private Circle a1;

    private Map<String, Circle> circles = new HashMap<>();

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        circles.put("A1", a1);
    }


    public void clickOnRectangleA(MouseEvent e) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(circles.containsValue(A1));
        circles.get("A1").setFill(SomeColor);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a bunch!